# Python: split by (different) n spaces

Tags: python, split

I have lines like this:

```
  2    20  164 "guid" Some name^7            0 ip.a.dd.res:port    -21630 25000

  6    30  139 "guid" Other name^7                0 ip.a.dd.res:port       932 25000
```

I would like to split this, but the problem is that there is different number of spaces between this "words"...

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python's split function doesn't care about the number of spaces:

```
>>> '  2    20  164 "guid" Some name^7            0 ip.a.dd.res:port    -21630 25000'.split()
['2', '20', '164', '"guid"', 'Some', 'name^7', '0', 'ip.a.dd.res:port', '-21630', '25000']
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know, that is soo smart :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `split()`? It will "compress" spaces, so after split you will get:

```
'2', '20', '164', '"guid'" etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> l = "1   2   4 'ds' 5  66"
>>> l
"1   2   4 'ds' 5  66"

>>> l.split(' ')
['1', '', '', '2', '', '', '4', "'ds'", '5', '', '66']

>>> [x for x in l.split()]
['1', '2', '4', "'ds'", '5', '66']
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use split() function. The delimiter is \s+ that is any kind and any number of space